# Rule with identical string token twice

Tags: yacc

Using yacc, I want to parse text like

```
begin foo ... end foo
```

The string `foo` is not known at compile time and there can be different
such strings in the same input.

So far, the only option I see is to check for syntactical correctness after parsing:

```
block : BEGIN IDENT something END IDENT 
        { if (strcmp($2, $5) != 0) yyerror("Mismatch"); }
```

This feels wrong. The parser should already detect the errors. Is there something built-in to yacc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yacc only knows about tokens which the lexer can identify. Since those are *identical*, the lexer could only improve this case by using *states*.

That is, you could tell lex to remember that it saw a `BEGIN` and to count the tokens itself, and return a different type of `IDENT` (and do the checking there).

However, yacc is better suited to this sort of thing, so the answer to the original question is "no", there is no better solution.